# Set environment variables (PATH, etc.) from script

Tags: environment-variables

How do I set the environment variables from a script?

Using `source scripts/setupenv.sh` doesn't seem to work.

I tried to use **sh** and **chmod +x** but it still doesn't work.

Comment: In what way does this not work? Does the script contain a shebang? (`#!/some/executable` at the beginning of the file)

Comment: I just cannot set the environment variables because I don't know which command to use!

Comment: That which you posted *is* the command to use (`source` runs the script you specify and retains the variables it sets in your current shell). Where did you get this command and what makes you think it doesn't work? What happens when you run that line?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and: 1/ post the contents of the script (precede every line with 4 spaces) and 2/post the output you get from a terminal ([Ctrl][Alt][T]) when you run the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very clear what you want to achieve. If you want to set some environment variables for the session, it's worth mentioning that there are existing files for the purpose such as `~/.profile`. Please see [EnvironmentVariables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Persistent_environment_variables) for more guidance.

Comment: Great to hear that, @Nora. It would be good if you could let us know *how* you fixed it, since this is a resource for sharing knowledge and experiences about Ubuntu.

Comment: I was typing the command at the wrong folder.

Comment: @Nora: Ok. The kind of mistake we all do once in a while. ;) Thanks for clarifying.